# Div's don't show in Internet Explorer but do show in chrome, firefox, opera etc

Tags: internet-explorer, html

Internet explorer is hiding some of my divs. They show up in all other browsers (even on mobile) but not in internet explorer. 
My site: http://www.colinch.com/media

I know the divs are a bit complicated with :hovers etc. but it should just work :s

Comment: Post the code having problem, try to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look quickly seems everything in a H1 tag

```
<div id="logo-bg">
<h1>
<a href="#">....etc
```

Comment: Such a small thing can cause so much trouble but thanks a lot man!! this really helped me out, can't thank you enough

Comment: o and can you flag it as Answered :)

Comment: Ok this is my first time on this website, I can't find the button to mark it as "answered"